# Polymorphic vs Normal database design in Laravel/MySql

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design, polymorphism

I'm designing a new app in Laravel and for its user part there is three type of users(student,agent,sponsor) and each got different properties. i have two choices:

1- create a one-to-one polymorphic relation by creating a user like this :

```
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->uuid('userable_id'); //polymorphic
            $table->string('userable_type'); //polymorphic
```

2- add user_id property to each table(student,agent,sponsor) and referring them to user table like this:

```
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->uuid('user_id'); //FK to user table
```

my question is which one is the best choice ? what is the pros/cons of each one ?
thank you.

Comment: Show the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs` of the generated database.  Then you can get an opinion from that side.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use number 1.

I already developed a Laravel app using method 2. The problem with this method is that you need to set three separate relations for each type of users on `User Model` (hasOne). Then whenever you need the relation, you have to check the user first and then call the related method (eg. if you need student, you need to check user if it is a student and then load the relation).

In method 1, you need to set only one relation on `User Model`. Then whenever you need to load the related model, you only need to call one method.

Hope this could help you in your decision.